# Nested notExists joins X++ (Dynamics AX3.0)

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

When the following code executes:

```
   select sum(qty) from inventTrans
        index hint TransTypeIdx
        where inventTrans.ItemId        == itemId
           && inventTrans.TransType     == InventTransType::Sales
           && inventTrans.InventDimId   == inventDimId
        notExists join custTable
        where custTable.AccountNum      == inventTrans.CustVendAC
           && custTable.CustGroup       == custGroupId
        notExists join salesTable
        where salesTable.SalesId        == inventTrans.TransRefId
           && salesTable.Extraordinary  == NoYes::Yes;
```

The sql generated nests the second notExists join (salesTable) into the where clause of the first notExists join (custTable). ie

```
SELECT SUM(A.QTY)
FROM
    INVENTTRANS A
WHERE
    A.DATAAREAID  = 'MyCompany'
AND A.ITEMID      = 'MyItem'
AND A.TRANSTYPE   = 0
AND A.INVENTDIMID = 'SomeValue'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                FROM CUSTTABLE C
                WHERE C.DATAAREAID  ='MyCompany'
                AND C.ACCOUNTNUM    =A.CUSTVENDAC
                AND C.CUSTGROUP     ='SomeCustGroup'
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                                FROM SALESTABLE B
                                WHERE
                                    B.DATAAREAID    ='MyCompany'
                                AND B.SALESID       =A.TRANSREFID
                                AND B.EXTRAORDINARY =1))
```

Is there any way to write the X++ select query to notExists join the salesTable to the inventTrans table instead of the custTable, so the SQL generated would be similar to the following?

```
SELECT SUM(A.QTY)
FROM
    INVENTTRANS A
WHERE A.DATAAREAID     = 'MyCompany'
AND A.ITEMID           = 'MyItem'
AND A.TRANSTYPE        = 0
AND A.INVENTDIMID      = 'SomeValue'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                FROM CUSTTABLE C
                WHERE C.DATAAREAID  ='MyCompany'
                AND C.ACCOUNTNUM    =A.CUSTVENDAC
                AND C.CUSTGROUP     ='SomeCustGroup')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                FROM SALESTABLE B
                WHERE
                    B.DATAAREAID='MyCompany'
                AND B.SALESID=A.TRANSREFID
                AND B.EXTRAORDINARY=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no!

In your example, you could reformulate using inner join:

```
select sum(qty) from inventTrans
    index hint TransTypeIdx
    where inventTrans.ItemId        == itemId
       && inventTrans.TransType     == InventTransType::Sales
       && inventTrans.InventDimId   == inventDimId
    join salesTable
    where salesTable.SalesId        == inventTrans.TransRefId
       && salesTable.Extraordinary  == NoYes::No;
    notExists join custTable
    where custTable.AccountNum      == inventTrans.CustVendAC
       && custTable.CustGroup       == custGroupId
```

It should work provided you do not delete sales orders when invoicing.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not waiting for an answer anymore, but on Ax 2012 I still experienced the same problem.

Found another solution (aside from using a SQL Statement), not the most performant one, but it works:

- Create a query: select * from inventTrans notexists join CustTable ....
- Create a view based on that query
- do the same for the salesTable
- change your select statement as follows:

  select inventTrans

  ...

  exists join myCustView

  where myCustView.InventTransRecId == inventTrans.RecId

  exists join mySalesView

  where ...

Hope this helps,

T