# Dynamics AX 2009: Or Exist Join in QueryBuildDataSource

Tags: t-sql, axapta, x++

I am want to use **OR EXISTS** clause in QueryBuildDataSource but i dont know how to use it.
I prepare sql query:

```
select * from LedgerJournalTable l
where
( 
   l.createdBy = '...' and l.WorkflowStatus != 99 
)
or exists 
( 
   select top 1 'x' from WorkflowWorkItemTable w 
   where l.RecId    = w.RefRecId 
   AND w.REFTABLEID = 211 
   and w.USERID     = '....'
)
```

and i try to build ax query

```
    queryDS = LedgerJournalTable_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(LedgerJournalTable));

    ledgerStatusFilter  = queryDS.addRange( fieldnum(LedgerJournalTable,WorkflowStatus) );
    ledgerUserFilter    = queryDS.addRange( fieldnum(LedgerJournalTable,createdBy) );

    ledgerStatusFilter.value( "!=99" );
    ledgerUserFilter.value( "..." );

    qbdsWorkItemtTable  = queryDS.addDataSource( tablenum(WorkflowWorkItemTable) );
    qbdsWorkItemtTable.joinMode( JoinMode::NoExistsJoin );
    qbdsWorkItemtTable.addLink( fieldnum(LedgerJournalTable,RecId), fieldnum(WorkflowWorkItemTable,RefRecId) );
    qbdsWorkItemtTable.addRange( fieldnum(WorkflowWorkItemTable,RefTableId) ).value( strfmt("%1",tablenum(LedgerJournalTable)));

    workflowUser        = qbdsWorkItemtTable.addRange( fieldnum( WorkflowWorkItemTable, UserId ) );

    workflowUser.value("...");

    info( strfmt("%1", queryDS.toString()  ) );
```

sory for my bad English :c

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but AX queries do not support `or exists`.

Also see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/514449/4509).